# Why assign method in pandas method chaining behave differently if it is applied in chain after group by?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to chain some methods in pandas but seems like order of methods is restrictive in Pandas.Let me explain this with mpg data.

In two of the below options, I have changed the order of the assign method. In option 1, it is before group by and it works as expected. While in option 2, it is after group by and it produces garbage output. In R/tidyverse I could simply do ungroup() and use mutate() either before or after group by and it would still produce the same output.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("mpg")
```

Option 1

```
(
 df
 .assign(origin=df.origin.map({'europe':'Europe'}).fillna(df.origin))
 .query(("origin=='Europe' & model_year==80"))
 .groupby(['origin','cylinders'],dropna=False)
 .mpg
 .sum()
 .reset_index()
)
```

Option 2

```
(
 df
 .query(("origin=='europe' & model_year==80"))
 .groupby(['origin','cylinders'],dropna=False)
 .mpg
 .sum()
 .reset_index()
 .assign(origin=df.origin.map({'europe':'Europe'}).fillna(df.origin))
)
```

The whole thing can also be done quite neatly without method chaining in Pandas but I am trying to see if I can make method chaining work for myself.

How can I ensure assign method in above two options produce same output regardless of where it is in the chain of methods?

Comment: Option 2 is querying "Europe" but the value is is still "europe"

Comment: In the second one, use a lambda in the assign. your `df` has changed, so a lambda allows U access to the changed `df`

Comment: Thanks Jason for pointing out I have fixed that in Option 2 now.

Comment: hi @sammywemmy tried .assign(origin = lambda df: 'Europe' if df.origin=='europe' else df.origin) but getting a value error

Comment: @itthrill Is that `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`? That's because of `if df.origin=='europe'`. IDK why you changed the expression, cause the old one works fine: `lambda df: df.origin.map({'europe':'Europe'}).fillna(df.origin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing here is actually the `.reset_index()`. In the original data, the first two rows have "usa" as their `origin`, so those get applied to the transformed data.

To illustrate, we can join (on the index):

```
tra = (
    df
    .query("origin=='europe' & model_year==80")
    .groupby(['origin', 'cylinders'], dropna=False)
    ['mpg'].sum()
    .reset_index()
)
tra.join(df['origin'], rsuffix='_2')
```

```
   origin  cylinders    mpg origin_2
0  europe          4  299.2      usa
1  europe          5   36.4      usa
```

To fix it, you could use a lambda to make use of the transformed data (as [sammywemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175713/sammywemmy) wrote in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74622393/why-assign-method-in-pandas-method-chaining-behave-differently-if-it-is-applied/74658346#comment131718480_74622393)):

```
tra.assign(origin=lambda df_:
    df_['origin'].map({'europe':'Europe'}).fillna(df_['origin'])
)
```

```
   origin  cylinders    mpg
0  Europe          4  299.2
1  Europe          5   36.4
```